# SQL Query to get rank, name and score from specific person

Tags: sql, mariadb, rank

I'm trying to get a rank, name and score from a specific player.

I used this query just to show the rank (I'm using this with PHP):

```
SELECT  count(*) + 1 AS rank
FROM scores
WHERE score > (SELECT score FROM scores WHERE name = '$name');
```

And I tried to get the name and score also this way:

```
SELECT  name, score, count(*) + 1 AS rank
FROM scores
WHERE score > (SELECT score FROM scores WHERE name = '$name');
```

But this returns the score and name from the player above me.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And learn to use parameters to pass constant values into your queries.

Comment: it looks like you dont want to get the name from a specific player but instead you want all those data for the person where the score is higher then that from another person?? or who is $name, and who do you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the rank *and* other information, I would suggest a subquery:

```
select s.*,
       (select count(*) + 1
        from scores s2
        where s2.score > s.score
       ) as rank
from s
where name = ?;
```

The `?` is a placeholder for a parameter name.  You can also use a named parameter.

Note:  This does not take ties into account.  If you are interested in that:

```
select s.*,
       (select count(distinct score)
        from scores s2
        where s2.score >= s.score
       ) as rank
from s
where name = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,score, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM user p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY  score DESC
```

Please use this query for rank calculation.in case of same score please use another parameter to calculate rank

example:  ORDER BY  score DESC,user_id desc like that.